# How to access the environment variables in Amazon S3 for the react application as I have stored the Firebase and Google Api Key in env variables?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, environment-variables, cicd

REACT_APP_API_KEY=**
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY=**

Using in the below style in react js for local environment :
process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY

Note : I am using aws code pipeline and code build for ci /cd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Code Build you can edit the Environment and add environmental variables. Click Additional configuration in the console to see it. You can export REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY there and you it should be picked up by `npm run build`.

You could also use an .env.production file and commit it to source code. These aren't secrets, are added to the deployed code, so there shouldn't be a security issue.

Comment: Thanks I am able access the key using the environment variable when I am using as plaintext and when trying to access through paramter getting access denied with error "phase context status code: Decrypted Variables Error Message: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::357976885335:assumed-role/codebuild-vehicle-doctor-frontend-f2-alpha-service-role/AWSCodeBuild-f7192431-8e0a-4611-8bea-3d857eafea95 is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameters on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:357976885335:parameter/FIREBASE_KEY because no identity-based policy allows the ssm:GetParameters action"

Comment: The message is clear. You need to give the code build IAM role ssm:GetParameters permission on the resource. Find the role in IAM console and add the permission.

Comment: I have already given the below policy to the Role ARN :arn:aws:iam::357976885335:role/service-role/codebuild-vehicle-doctor-frontend-f2-alpha-service-role but still getting access denied

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:357976885335:parameter/CodeBuild/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Is this a typo? The error is for arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:357976885335:parameter/FIREBASE_KEY and you are granting access to arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:357976885335:parameter/CodeBuild/*. Although it isn't a good practice, try first with '*' and then try to restrict it.

Comment: Should I change to arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:357976885335:parameter/FIREBASE_KEY/*?

Comment: Try  arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:357976885335:parameter/FIREBASE_KEY